# PHP session / json / javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, session

I need to figure out why i cannot get this Session to JS for a JSON object. I am sure i missing something simple.

I have a Session var being set in laravel

```
Session::put('test', "{'test1':'123','test2':'456'}");
```

I want to set this in a page in js :

```
<script>var testvar = "{{\Session::get('test')}}";
```

then i try and do this in js :

```
var test_json = JSON.parse(testvar);
```

but i am seeing the js testvar is set with the quotes encoded?

what i am i doing wrong???

Comment: why do you want to use `Session` in a blade? You need to pass these values as parameters to the blade, respecting MVC.

Comment: 1. That's not [JSON](http://json.org), 2. [There's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @Andreas If it walks like a duck and talks like a duck, it's a json object. :)~

Comment: @JustinSchwimmer If something is wrong, its wrong. Just because there's a site that's using the wrong term for it doesn't make it correct.

Comment: @Andreas If it's wrong - we have to right a wrong. And sometimes, in order to right a wrong, you have to do a wrong-right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The problem

Your following code

```
<script>
   var testvar = "{{\Session::get('test')}}";
   var data = JSON.parse(testvar);
</script>
```

would be interpreted as:

```
<script>
   var testvar = {'test1':'123','test2':'456'};
   var data = JSON.parse(testvar);
</script>
```

`{'test1':'123','test2':'456'}` is invalid JSON, as you need to use double quotes instead of single quotes.

So you need:

```
Session::put('test', '{"test1":"123","test2":"456"}');
```

But this creates another problem.

Laravel auto escapes HTML for security reasons to avoid XSS attacks.

This means the above is now interpreted as :

```
<script>
    var testvar = {&quot;test1&quot;:&quot;123&quot;,&quot;test2&quot;:&quot;456&quot;}&quot;
    var data = JSON.parse(testvar);
</script>
```

If you are sure the data you are storing is safe, you can use raw tags like so, and avoid using `JSON.parse` (so we don't need to re-escape any of the quotes again) like so:

```
<script>
    var testvar = {!! Session::get('test') !!};
</script>
```

This will then output the HTML:

```
<script>
    var testvar = {"test1":"123", "test2":"456"};
</script>
```

### A better solution

A better way is to store your data as an array in the PHP session:

```
Session::put('test', [
    'test1' => '123',
    'test2' => '456'
]);
```

Then you could just do:

```
<script>
    var testvar = @json(Session::get('test'));
</script>
```

This is explained here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#displaying-data

### Side Note

As a side note, consider passing a variable into blade to avoid doing logic in your views like so:

```
return view('your-view-name', [
    'testvar' => Session::get('test'),
]);
```

Then you could just do:

```
<script>
    var testvar = @json($testvar);
</script>
```

Comment: The properties (and if required also the values) have to be wrapped in double quotes

Comment: No they don't.  I think your getting confused with JSON. JavaScript objects allows BOTH single and double quoted properties and values.

Comment: i dont understand ... are you saying to set an array in Session var and then do this ?    var app = @json(Session::get('test'));

Comment: I provided 2 solutions. If the session data cannot be changed, then use raw blade tags. However it would be better to set the session data as an array, instead of encoded JSON data, and use `var testvar = @json(Session::get('test'));`.

Comment: This seems *almost* right, but: 1) the original code was attempting to pass *the JSON string* to JS and parse it with `JSON.parse`, whereas this code echoes the JSON string so the browser evaluates it directly as code; 2) I don't see where the `&quot;` will come from in the example code, because the value of the session variable begins with `{` not `"`.

Comment: In your first version of the answer you were using `"{!! Session::get('test') !!}"` which would have to be parsed because otherwise it would only be a string. And for this to be valid JSON the properties would have to be wrapped in double quotes which wouldn't be the case with the setup of TO (`Session::put('test', "{'test1':'123','test2':'456'}");`)

Comment: need quotes around test1? test2?    Session::put('test', [
    test1 => '123',
    test2 => '456'
]);

Comment: ok lets assume i can set session var as array.... what is correct way then

Comment: The bit under "A Better Solution"

Comment: ok so i tried this - i am just not getting results here on this   var my_json = @json(\Session::get('test'));  i get SyntaxError: illegal character

Comment: What laravel version are you using and what is the HTML output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184051/discussion-between-tebowner-and-yahya-uddin).